# get contacts from 2nd screen to 1st screen and list it react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I want to send msg to my contact. and i get access to contact book also but when i pass data to 1st screen  from 2nd im unable to create flat list from it. Setting 2nd screen data to state also.

Please go to react native expo link and check source code.expo required mobile apk to run properly.

here is my react expo link

**https://snack.expo.io/@vikraant/bulk-check**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
import DateTimePicker from "react-native-modal-datetime-picker";
import {
  TextInput,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  ProgressBarAndroid,
  FlatList,
  ActivityIndicator,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Keyboard
} from 'react-native';

export default class BulkInvitationActivity extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.clientId = Constants.deviceId; 
    this.state = {usr_mobile:[] }

  }
  onSelect = (data) =>{
    this.setState(data)
  }

  contactlist = () =>{
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Contact',{ onSelect: this.onSelect });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container} behavior='padding'>
      <View style={styles.SectionStyle}>
      <Text style={[{ width: "60%",margin:'auto'}]}>Add Guest</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity style={[{ width: 100,margin:'auto',textTransform:'lowercase'}]}
      onPress = {this.contactlist}>
      <Text style = {styles.submitButtonText}>contacts</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View style={{width:'95%'}}>
      <Text>{JSON.stringify(this.state.usr_mobile)}</Text>
      <FlatList     
      data={this.state.usr_mobile}
      extraData={this.state.usr_mobile}
      renderItem={({ item }) =>
      (
        <Text style={{backgroundColor:'gray',color:'#fff',border:1,margin:2,padding:5}}>{item.mobileno}</Text>
        )}
        enableEmptySections={true}
        style={{ marginTop: 10 }}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        />
        </View>
        <View>
        <TouchableOpacity style={[{ width: "90%",margin:'auto',textTransform:'lowercase'}]}>
        <Text style = {styles.submitButtonText}>Send Invitation</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        );
      }
    }
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        display:'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        flexDirection: 'column'
      },
      submitButtonText:{
        textAlign:'center',
        padding:10,
        color:'#fff',
        backgroundColor:'#062c47',
        // width: "100%"

      },
      SectionStyle: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5F6F7',
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#000',
        height: 40,
        borderRadius: 5,
        marginTop: 50,
      }
      });
```

2nd screen code -

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
import * as Contacts from 'expo-contacts';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    FlatList,
    Button,
    Alert,
    View,
    CheckBox,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Text,
    Platform,
    PermissionsAndroid,
} from 'react-native';

export default class ContactList extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={item:'',check:{},selecteditem:[]}
    }

    async componentDidMount(){
        let {status} = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CONTACTS);
        if (status=='granted') {
            let contact = await Contacts.getContactsAsync();
            // console.log(contact);
            this.setState({ item:contact.data})
        }else{
            alert(status);
        }
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        console.log(e.nativeEvent);
        if (e.nativeEvent.value==true) {
            e.nativeEvent.value=='false';
        }
    }

    select_contact(number){
        const checkCopy = {...this.state.check}
        if (checkCopy[number]) checkCopy[number] = false;
        else checkCopy[number] = true;
        this.setState({ check: checkCopy });
        console.log(this.state.check);
    }
    back = () =>{
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Product');
        this.props.navigation.state.params.onSelect({ usr_mobile:this.state.check});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
            <Text onPress = {this.back.bind(this)} style={{padding:5,margin:5,backgroundColor:'#000', textAlign:"center",color:'#fff',}}>Back</Text>
            <FlatList
            data={this.state.item}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
                <View style={{padding:10,flexDirection:'row'}}>
                <CheckBox
                value = { this.state.check[item.phoneNumbers[0].number] }
                onChange = {() => this.select_contact(item.phoneNumbers[0].number) } 
                ></CheckBox> 
                <Text style={{padding:2}}>{item.firstName}</Text>
                </View>
                )}
                enableEmptySections={true}
                style={{ marginTop: 10 }}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                />
                </View>
                );
            }
        }
        const styles = StyleSheet.create({
            container: {
                flex: 1,
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
            },
            input: {
                width: "90%",
                height: 44,
                padding: 10,
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: 'black',
                marginBottom: 10,
            },
            logbtn: {
                width: "90%",
                padding: 15,
                margin: 5
            }
        });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the onselect method in the 1st screen, it should be this.setState(usr_mobile : data);

Comment: it already setting state but i'cant create flatlist . @Sanjay

Comment: I strongly have the feeling that you are using state and props in the wrong way.. Think in that direction and check if you have the data or not just before rendering the flatlist(check just before rendering). If you have the data, then it means that you are passing the data to the flatlist in the wrong way.. If you don't  have the data, then you know what to do

Comment: i tried every possiblities which i know. can you review code or go to link @Sanjay

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the contact list as props, you can get them like this `{...this.props}`

Comment: getting data but can't create flatlist from it. @kodak